# Ошибка при использовании указателей в c#

Tags: c#, c, указатели, fixed

Переписываю код с Си на C#. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Вот код на си.

```
int right[2 * par - 1];
int left[2 * par - 1];
...

void func()
{
   int *p;
   // some code
   if (k & mask)
     p = &right[*p];
   else
     p = &left[*p];
}
```

А вот мой вариант на C#.

```
int[] right = new int[2 * par - 1];
int[] right = new int[2 * par - 1];
...
 unsafe void func()
{
  int *p;
  //some code
  if ((k & mask) != 0)
    p = &right[*p];
  else
    p = &left[*p];
}
```

В if VS выдаёт следующую ошибку

> Адрес нефиксированного выражения можно получить только внутри
>   инициализатора оператора fixed

Пока не понимаю, как решить проблему, используя этот оператор. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

**P.S.** 
используя оператор `fixed`, как показано в примере из [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f58wzh21(v=vs.120)), ничего не получилось, поскольку в том примере необходимо в круглых скобках писать конструкцию типа `int *p = &variable`, а у меня уже в начале кода идёт объявление `int *p`, и в процессе работы оно успешно присваивается и изменяется, но вот доходя до `if`, вылетает ошибка.

Comment: я психанул) есть, но такая редкость и моветон использовать их в c#

Comment: Понимаю, и всё же хотелось бы понять, как решить проблему.

Comment: попробуйте использовать fixed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f58wzh21(v=vs.120)

Comment: Так собственно, в этом вопрос и состоит: как правильно его тут использовать

Comment: да уж, что-то я совсем замотался, видимо, сегодня...прикрепите к вопросу, как вы пробовали и почему не получилось, пожалуйста

Comment: @PavelNewSky, хорошо.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73194/discussion-between-pavelnewsky-and-setplus).

Comment: Не понял, а зачем там в C# небезопасные указатели? В большинстве случаев это можно обойти. Массив - это и так ссылочный тип в шарпе. Можно просто написать `int[] p=null;`, а потом присваивать `p=right;`

Comment: ...как то примерно так. А с индексами - завести переменную для индекса, или массив делать не int, а из ссылочных обёрток. `Tuple<int>[]` например.

Comment: А вообще, код больше похож на какой то обход связанного списка или цепочки, и идёт работа с индексом. Так что есть смысл объявить просто `int p;`, и сохранять туда значение `p=right[p];`.

Answer (score 4):

Переписывать подобный код на C# "в лоб" - не лучшая идея.

Фактически, в этом коде указатель `p` используется для обозначения сразу массива и его элемента. И раз уж язык C# не дает так делать - можно вернуться к полной форме:

```
int[] parray;
int pindex;

//some code
if ((k & mask) != 0)
{
    int v = parray[pindex]; // Ранее *p
    parray = right;
    pindex = v;
}
else
{
    int v = parray[pindex]; // Ранее *p
    parray = left;
    pindex = v;
}
```

Если подобного кода много - можно завести себе в помощь структуру, которая будет себя вести аналогично указателю на ячейку массива:

```
struct ArrayCell<T>
{
    private readonly T[] array;
    private readonly int index;

    public ArrayCell(T[] array, int index)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return array[index]; }
        set { array[index] = value; }
    }
}

static class ArrayCellExtensions
{
    public static ArrayCell<T> Cell<T>(this T[] array, int index) => new ArrayCell<T>(array, index); // Немного сахара
}

// ...

ArrayCell<int> p;

//some code
if ((k & mask) != 0)
    p = right.Cell(p.Value);
else
    p = left.Cell(p.Value);
```

Comment: Если честно, не очень понимаю, как работает строка `int v = parray[ pindex]`...

Comment: @Setplus а что непонятного в обращении к элементу массива?

Comment: то, что идёт обращение к элементу массива ... через переменную массива...

Comment: @Setplus а что не так? Почему left вас не смущает, а parray - смущает?

Comment: Вместо `struct ArrayCell<T>` можно использовать ключевое слово `ref` (Ссылочные локальные переменные)

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, вроде бы уже можно...

Answer (score 1):

Здесь два варианта, если массивы создаются и живут внутри функции, и их размер небольшой то можно их выделить на стеке:

```
int* right = stackalloc int[2 * par - 1];
...
if ((k & mask) != 0)
    p = &right[*p];
```

В вашем случае это не ок, потому что размер массива у вас переменный, можно нарваться на StackOverflow );
Вариант два, зафиксировать расположение в памяти:

```
 fixed (int* _right = &right[0], _left = &left[0])
 {
      ...
      if ((k & mask) != 0)
           p = &_right[*p];
 }
```

Работать с укзателями на массив, можно только внутри блока фиксед. 
Можно схитрить и написать как-нибудь:

```
if ((k & mask) != 0)
   fixed(int* ptr = &right[*p]) { p = ptr; }
```

но первая же сборка мусора, может переместить данные куда угодно  и указатель соответственно станет не валиден.

p.s.
 у вас проблема не в присваивании p и не в if, а в попытке взять адрес массива который не закреплен в памяти.