# указатели в c#, fixed

Tags: c#, c, указатели

Есть строка кода в Си:

```
p = &table[k];
```

Надо такое же сделать на C#. В проекте включаем Allow Unsafe Mode и пишем:

```
unsafe
{
    int* p;
    p = &table[k];
}
```

VS пишет, что

> адрес нефиксированного выражения можно получить только внутри
>   инициализатора оператора fixed.

Порылся в инете, предлагали вариант:

```
int* p = &table[k];
```

но VS упорно пишет тоже самое. Не пойму, как исправить это недоразумение.

Comment: Возможно вам поможет вот этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785632/178779

Answer (score 2):

[fixed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement)

```
fixed (int* p = &table[k])
{
    // *p = ...;
}
```